# change email script to open a php page upon success

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, email

I'm using an email script that gives me a success statement in a div (#errorEmail).

Instead I would like to execute "inv_fc_mail_success.php" upon success.

How would I replace this line:    success: function(){$('#errorEmail').html('Email Sent');

```
if (validateEmail(email)&& email!=""){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: "inv_fc_mail.php?email="+email,
      success: function(){
      $('#errorEmail').html('Email Sent');
      setTimeout(function(){$("#FCemail").dialog('close', function()   
      {$('#errorEmail').hide();});}, 3000);

      }
    });
}
else {$('#errorEmail').html('Email Not Valid').show();}
```

Comment: You would want to start *another* Ajax request inside the success method

Comment: By `execute "inv_fc_mail_success.php"` do you mean open the page? Or send another ajax call?

Comment: Yes. I would like to close this dialogue window (via jqMODAL) and open the other php page as stated in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect your browser to your success page:

```
window.location = "inv_fc_mail_success.php";
```

Note that the `window.` reference is unnecessary in most up to date browsers, but it's good pratice to keep it compatible with older ones as well.

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)**

Or more specifically:

```
success: function(){ window.location = "inv_fc_mail_success.php"; }
```

Comment: You mean success: function(){window.location"inv_fc_mail_success.php";}

Comment: yes, that goes inside your `success`'s anonymous function. :) Don't forget the `=`.

Comment: Also, you said something about `jqModal`, but I don't see any related code to it. Redirecting the `location` of your page will cause the modal to close automatically, edit your question if you happen to have any issue with `jqModal`.

Answer (score 1):

2 possibilities:

1. Another ajax call inside the success section
2. Skip Ajax altogether, just redirect to the php page you want